# Importing SCSS variables in Vue components

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I recently switched from Vue-CLI to laravel-mix, the usage of SCSS variables worked perfectly with Vue-CLI and now doesnt seem to work anymore at all after I switched to laravel-mix.

Vue-CLI just handled everything for me and I feel like I have to configure something to get the variables to work in laravel-mix.

This is what I've tried (and what worked with Vue-CLI):

```
// vue component
import variables from "@/styles/variables.scss";
// ...
data() {
    return {
        variables
    }
}
methods: {
    test() {
        console.log(this.variables)
    }
}
```

```
// scss
$variable: #FFFFFF;

:export {
    variable: $variable;
}
```

Edit: To clarify, this log outputs an empty object, not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For this thing to work you need to follow that particular steps

- Make Your Variables File. As you made your scss file inside your style its not good you need to make inside /assets/sass/
- Add Variables File To App.scss. For that thing you need to import newly create file inside your app.scss by @import 'folder/file';
- Add Alias To webpack.mix.js. What we essentially need to do is define an alias or variable that contains the path to our sass directory so we can include that SASS in our Vue components. Just add alias like this in your webpack

  ```
  resolve: {
   alias: {
       '@': path.resolve('resources/assets/sass')
   }   
  }
  ```
- Last thing add Navigation Vue Component. You can import scss variables by adding @import '~@/folder/fie.scss'; in the vue component

Comment: 1. Why do I need to put the variables.scss file into /assets/sass/?
Im working with a template and Im not trying to mess around in their project structure...
2. The variables.scss file is imported into the main scss file (index.scss in my case)
3. I have an alias like this, but I'm trying to use the scss variables in Javascript, not in CSS...

Comment: so in that case you have to import style/file.scss in main app.scss file and then make alias in webpackmix and use that in your template

Comment: Its not about messing the project actually these are conventions you should follow these otherwise there is a mess

Comment: If you look at my post, you'll see that I have an alias. I did import the variables.scss file in my index.scss (main scss file). And I DID use the alias in my vue component, like you see in my "vue component" example.

Comment: Well but I can't / don't want to mess with the directory structure of this template because this will only lead to more problems and refactoring which I can't afford to do. It worked totally fine with Vue-CLI.

Comment: I think for that thing importing scss from styles you need to modify rules and add saas loader in the webpack config. Just change webpack config like this
 .webpackConfig({
      resolve: {
         alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/sass'),
         },
      },
      module: {
         rules: [
            {
               test: /\.scss$/,
               loader: "sass-loader",
               options: {
                  data: `
                        @import "~@/style/vars.scss";
                  `
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   })

Comment: Then I get a ton of this error: 
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }